# Integration procedure error "Invalid conversion from runtime type String to Decimal"

Tags: vlocity

I am a new Omnistudio dev and I am trouble shooting a Integration Procedure that I did not create. The first error received was SOQL Query limit. After the Vlocity Winter '22 update, it seemed to work but got this error:
[image]

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to clarify "OS" and "IP".  Also, have you checked the Salesforce Known Issues page?